# Allow Paging for HTML list

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, sharepoint

I am building a SharePoint web part that creates a HTML list as below

```
<ul>
   <li> ... </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to enable paging on this list using Javascript because the list is too long?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this jquery plugin:
http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/20/simplepager---jquery-paging-plugin--updated

Demo here:
http://geckohub.com/jquery/simplepager/